# Python: Is there a way of knowing whether an instance of a class has been assigned to a variable?

Tags: python, class, variables, instance

I am writing a Body2D class, and under the `__add__()` magic method I would like to be able to know whether an instance of the class is actually assigned to a variable, or whether it was created just for the addition.

For example, how would I be able to tell the difference between this:

```
earth = Body2D()
venus = Body2D()
mars = earth + venus
```

... where both first instances are tied to a variable, and this:

```
mars = Body2D() + Body2D()
```

?

The reason I ask is because I have created a class variable (a list) of all the IDs of the objects created so far, and I don't want to store IDs of bodies that have not been assigned to variables.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `bodies = map(some_f, (Body2D(), Body2D())`. Now what? Will this be saved, won’t it be? This is fundamentally a wrong approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible. From the perspective of your class instances, *nothing* changes at the moment of assignment aside from their reference count *failing* to be decremented, since the reference count is incremented when they're loaded onto the stack; popping from the stack to store to a variable transfers ownership to the variable, that's all. This isn't C++ where assignment involves constructor or assignment operators being invoked to execute custom code; in the general case, there is *zero* instance observable difference between creating an object temporarily and creating it for longer term storage in a named variable.

I suspect [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040) here, and in all likelihood your true solution will end up using [the `weakref` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) in some way to track which objects remain referenced (without holding a reference yourself that would prevent the objects from being cleaned up).

Comment: Side-note: I'm describing reference counts, which are a feature of the CPython reference interpreter (the one most people think of when they say "Python"). For other interpreters using more modern garbage collection systems, you'd lose even the ability to design bad heuristics based on reference counts (because they don't have them), making this even more impossible.

Comment: This is incredibly useful, thank you very much. I had not thought of that! At least I can be calm now in the knowledge that it is impossible :P in any case, it does not affect my end goal which is not having two Body2D objects with the same ID, so all is well! Thanks again